# How to increase speed of Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I collect data from twitter and store it on hdfs. I want to take these tweets sorted according to timestamp, but this query takes a lot of time.

1.5 gb data takes 1 minutes to sort and I think it is much more than expected.

What can be done to speed this query?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect anything faster from Hive. On our Prod cluster, the typical overhead for a query involving a MapReduce DAG of batch jobs is 20 seconds - and that's with a lean-and-mean JDBC connection; with Hive CLI there are another 20s just to start the JVM and warm-up a TEZ container.

If you need the response times of a relational DBMS, just use MySQL. Or maybe a distributed thing like the free version of MemSQL.